# How to In R read through each row to determine the value of a certain cell

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

My dataframe looks like this:

```
code = c("BIOL", "HIST","ECON","ANTH","FREN","MGMT")
Room = c("A", "B", "A","B","C","C")
df <- data.frame(code, Room)
```

and I have three lists as follow:

```
Sci_codes = c("BIOL", "ANTH", "FREN")
art_codes = c("Hist", "MYTH")
bussiness_codes = c("ECON", "MGMT")
```

I want to create a new column called faculty based on the value in the Code column. If a string in code is found in the Sci_codes list, I want it to return "Sci." If the value in the code column is found in the art_codes list, I want it to return "Art." Finally, if the value in the code column is found in the bussiness_codes list, I want it to return "Bussiness."

So in theory my data frame would look like this

```
df <- data.frame(code = c("BIOL", "HIST","ECON","ANTH","FREN","MGMT"),
                 Room = c("A", "B", "A","B","C","C"),
                 faculty = c("Sci", "Art", "Bussiness", "Sci", "Sci", "Bussiness"))
```

I am new at R, so I don't really know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical thing in R is to use a formula to define the values for a new/updated column, and then R will apply it to the data frame using the values from each row. This is called a "vectorized" operation, where R applies the calculation to one or more vectors all at once. (Each column of a data frame being a vector.)

We can define a new column `faculty` by assigning something to `df$faculty`. Below are two examples, using the `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when` functions, to use a series of TRUE/FALSE tests to assign values.

`dplyr::case_when` might be useful here, more elegant than a nested `ifelse`:

```
df$faculty = dplyr::case_when(
  df$code %in% Sci_codes ~ "Sci",
  df$code %in% art_codes ~ "Art",
  df$code %in% bussiness_codes ~ "Business"
)
```

If we have used `art_codes = c("HIST", "MYTH")` we'd get:

```
  code Room  faculty
1 BIOL    A      Sci
2 HIST    B      Art
3 ECON    A Business
4 ANTH    B      Sci
5 FREN    C      Sci
6 MGMT    C Business
```

Using base R ifelse:

```
df$faculty = ifelse(df$code %in% Sci_codes, "Sci",
                    ifelse(df$code %in% art_codes, "Art",
                           ifelse(df$code %in% bussiness_codes, "Business",
                                  "unknown")))
```

Answer (score 0):

base R:

```
merge(df,stack(mget(ls(pattern = "codes$")))|>
   transform(code = toupper(values), faculty = sub("_.*", '', ind)),
    sort = FALSE)[c(names(df), 'faculty')]

  code Room   faculty
1 BIOL    A       Sci
2 HIST    B       art
3 ECON    A bussiness
4 ANTH    B       Sci
5 FREN    C       Sci
6 MGMT    C bussiness
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)

v <- list(Sci = Sci_codes, Business = bussiness_codes, Art = art_codes)

df %>%
   left_join(enframe(v, 'faculty', 'code') %>%
               unnest_longer('code') %>%
               mutate(code = toupper(code)), 'code')

  code Room  faculty
1 BIOL    A      Sci
2 HIST    B      Art
3 ECON    A Business
4 ANTH    B      Sci
5 FREN    C      Sci
6 MGMT    C Business
```